# Text wrapping incorrectly in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

To provide help to users - a div appears when they click on a question mark:

A javascript function makes the div appear:

```
function showhelpby(whichdiv,e,divwidth,leftorright,message)
{
    e=(!e)?window.event:e;//IE:Moz

    document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.width = divwidth + 'px';
    if (leftorright == 'left')
    {
        if (e.pageX)
        {
        document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.left = e.pageX - divwidth - 20 + 'px';
        document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
        }
        else if(e.clientX)
        {
        document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.left = window.event.clientX - divwidth - 20 + 'px';
        document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.top = window.event.clientY + 'px';    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.pageX)
        {
        document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.left = e.pageX + 20 + 'px';
        document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
        }
        else if(e.clientX)
        {
        document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.left = window.event.clientX + 20 + 'px';
        document.getElementById(whichdiv).style.top = window.event.clientY + 'px';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = message;
}
```

The css for the divs that appear is:

```
div.notes
{
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 12px;
color: #000066;
line-height:140%;
display:none;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color:#000099;
position:absolute;
padding:15px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
background-image:url(images/F3F3F3White200.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
z-index:201;
}
```

And the text that shows within the divs is in `<p>` tags with no css styles applied.

I have been using the above for years to show little 'help' divs that pop up.

Now, all of a sudden, developing a site in Visual Studio 2010 - for use on an intranet - being viewed (after publishing) using IE 9 (we have to use IE) - the text in my help divs does not wrap properly. **The text appears justified and words just break wherever they want**. This has nothing to do with long words not breaking. The word 'the' may end up with the 't' on one line and the 'he' on the next.

Apart from the usual muttering about 'bloody Internet Explorer - can they do NOTHING right?' - anyone know what I need to do to get something as basic as text wrapping properly within a fixed width div?

Comment: Sounds like the text in your popup is influenced by the document's css. Did you have a look in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: The code posted can hardly produce the problem described. Please provide a self-contained document that demonstrates the problem. (The odds are that some tool you are using injects a CSS rule that causes the problem.)

Comment: But what css rule could say to the word 'the' to break on 't' and put 'he' on the next line?

Comment: Looks okay in Firefox - is this something to do with IE's compatability mode? I really don't want to have to tell every user to run IE 9.0 in compatability mode for intranet sites - just to make text wrap properly.

Comment: Please try and recreate the problem on jsfiddle.net so we can play around with it there.

Comment: Okay, adding white-space:normal to the paragraph tags that appear within the div fixed it.
Never had to do that before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding word-break:normal?
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp